# "To start" or "to starting"

Tags: infinitives

While I was attempting online ISL test, where I got the following MCQ:

> Chen's looking forward ______ his job next week.
>
> **a)** to starting
>
> **b)** to start
>
> **c)** starting
>
> **d)** in starting

The ISL considered the option "to starting" as a correct. But I think that the correct option is "to start" because we don't use -ing form after to-infinitive.

So which one is correct?

> - Chen's looking forward **to starting** his job next week.

OR

> - Chen's looking forward **to start** his job next week.

Comment: "To starting" is correct in that context.

Comment: We would say 'Chen's expecting to start his job next week' - but what we look forward to is an event.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a case of to-infinitive, but rather the phrasal verb "[look forward to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/look-forward-to)", which pairs either with a noun or a gerund.